# Trying to get appSettings.json settings in an ILogger provider

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side, ilogger, iloggerfactory

The ILogger provider I created runs fine. But I have two problems:

1. The appSettings.json are not passed in to the provider constructor.
2. The logging system ignores the appSettings.json set specifically for my provider.

appSettings.json:

```json
"Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning",
        "LouisHowe": "Information",
        "ThirdPartyServices": "Information",
        "CommonUtilities": "Information",
        "Microsoft": "Warning"
    },

    "File": {
        "Path": "C:/temp/log-{yyyy-MM-dd}.txt",
        "Interval": "Day",
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Information",
            "LouisHowe": "Trace",
            "Microsoft": "Warning"
        }
    },
```

The options classes:

```csharp
public class FileLoggerOptions
{
    public string? Path { get; set; } = "";
    public string? Interval { get; set; } = "";
}

internal class FileLoggerOptionsSetup : ConfigureFromConfigurationOptions<FileLoggerOptions>
{
    public FileLoggerOptionsSetup(ILoggerProviderConfiguration<FileLoggerProvider> providerConfiguration)
        : base(providerConfiguration.Configuration)
    {
    }
}
```

The provider constructors:

```csharp
public FileLoggerProvider(IOptionsMonitor<FileLoggerOptions> options)
    : this(options.CurrentValue)
{
    _settingsChangeToken = options.OnChange(opt => { _options = opt; });
}

public FileLoggerProvider(FileLoggerOptions options)
{
    options.Path = "C:/temp/log-{yyyy-MM-dd}.txt";
    _options = options;
}
```

And how it is added in Program.cs:

```csharp
public static ILoggingBuilder AddFileLogger(this ILoggingBuilder builder)
{
    builder.AddConfiguration();

    builder.Services.TryAddEnumerable(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<ILoggerProvider, 
        FileLoggerProvider>());
    builder.Services.TryAddEnumerable(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IConfigureOptions<FileLoggerOptions>, 
        FileLoggerOptionsSetup>());
    builder.Services.TryAddEnumerable(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IOptionsChangeTokenSource<FileLoggerOptions>, 
        LoggerProviderOptionsChangeTokenSource<FileLoggerOptions, FileLoggerProvider>>());
    return builder;
}
```

I can do the following to get the configuration. But I want to understand why the above doesn't work. And the following does not get it to use the LogLevels set under File.

```csharp
public FileLoggerProvider(IConfiguration config)
{
    _options = config.GetSection("Logging:File").Get<FileLoggerOptions>();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. So simple, once you know what it is. Need the following attribute:

```
[ProviderAlias("File")]
public class FileLoggerProvider : ILoggerProvider, IAsyncDisposable
```

And that makes sense. It needs to know what I named it in appSettings.json. With that added, it all works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow my steps to implement it.

**Here is the test result.**

[image]

*My project structure.*

[image]

*appsettings.json*

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning",
      "LouisHowe": "Information",
      "ThirdPartyServices": "Information",
      "CommonUtilities": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning"
    },

    "File": {
      "Path": "C:/temp/log-{0:yyyy-MM-dd}.txt",
      "Interval": "Day",
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information",
        "LouisHowe": "Trace",
        "Microsoft": "Warning"
      }
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

*FileLoggerExtensions.cs*

```
namespace ilogger_sink
{

    // Extension method to add custom file logger
    public static class FileLoggerExtensions
    {
        public static ILoggingBuilder AddFileLogger(this ILoggingBuilder builder, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<ILoggerProvider, FileLoggerProvider>();
            builder.Services.Configure<FileLoggerOptions>(configuration.GetSection("Logging:File"));
            return builder;
        }
    }
}
```

*FileLoggerProvider.cs*

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

namespace ilogger_sink
{
    public class FileLoggerProvider : ILoggerProvider
    {
        private readonly FileLoggerOptions? _options;

        public FileLoggerProvider(IOptions<FileLoggerOptions> options)
        {
            _options = options.Value;
        }

        public ILogger CreateLogger(string categoryName)
        {
            return new FileLogger(_options.Path);
        }

        public void Dispose() { }
    }

}
```

*FileLoggerOptions.cs*

```
namespace ilogger_sink
{
    // File logger options
    public class FileLoggerOptions
    {
        public string? Path { get; set; }
    }
}
```

*FileLogger.cs*

```
namespace ilogger_sink
{
    public class FileLogger : ILogger
    {
        private readonly string? _logDirectory;
        private readonly string? _logFileFormat;

        public FileLogger(string logPathFormat)
        {
            _logDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(logPathFormat);
            _logFileFormat = Path.GetFileName(logPathFormat);
        }

        public IDisposable? BeginScope<TState>(TState state) => null;

        public bool IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel) => true;

        public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
        {
            if (!IsEnabled(logLevel))
                return;

            string message = formatter(state, exception);

            // Using string format to insert the current date into the filename
            string filename = String.Format(_logFileFormat, DateTime.UtcNow);
            string logFilePath = Path.Combine(_logDirectory, filename);

            try
            {
                System.IO.File.AppendAllText(logFilePath, message + Environment.NewLine);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Failed to log message: {ex}");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

*Program.cs*

```
...
namespace ilogger_sink
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
            builder.Logging.AddConsole();

            builder.Logging.AddFileLogger(builder.Configuration);

            // Add services to the container.
            builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
            ...

            var app = builder.Build();

            ...
            app.Run();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but your solution is basically the same as the one I listed above that does work. And it has the same problems:

1. The logging system does not pay attention to the File.LogLevel settings.

2. It is not using IOptionsMonitor and therefore the logger will not be notified if the appSettings.json file is changed.

There clearly is a way to achieve both of the above issues as other loggers do this. Any idea how?